# Kerberos Authentication header for JAX-WS client

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, kerberos, wsimport, spnego

I am generating my web service using `ws-import` to connect to an aspx service that I have secured with Kerberos on IIS.
I am able to connect and authenticate fine when I just connect to the service using a `SOAPConnection`

```
final SOAPConnection conn = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
try {
    final MessageFactory msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    final SOAPMessage message = msgFactory.createMessage();

    final MimeHeaders headers = message.getMimeHeaders();
    if (spnegoToken != null) {
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld");
        headers.addHeader("Authorization", "Negotiate " + Base64.encode(spnegoToken));
    }
   message.getSOAPBody().addBodyElement(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "HelloWorld", "tem"));
   final SOAPMessage response = conn.call(
       message, "http://server:9994/WebService/SampleService.asmx");
   return response.getSOAPBody().getTextContent();
   } finally {
       conn.close();
   }
```

However I am unable to add an Authorization header to the JAXWS generated WS in the same way:

```
   final SampleServiceSoap sss= new SampleService().getSampleServiceSoap();
   ((BindingProvider) sss).getRequestContext().put(
       "Authorization", "Negotiate " + Base64.encode(spnegoToken));
   return sss.helloWorld();
```

I get a 401 error as the token as I cannot see the token attached in Wireshark.
Can anyone point me at the approach I should take?
Cheers,
Barry

Answer (score 2):

Sorted, turns out I was pretty close:

```
final Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

headers.put("Authorization", Collections.singletonList("Negotiate " + Base64.encode(tgt)));

((BindingProvider) sss).getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```